# What is a JSON-safe object?

Tags: javascript, json

In Kyle Simpson's book [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md), he writes this on the subject of how to duplicate an object:

> One subset solution is that objects which are JSON-safe (that is, can be serialized to a JSON string and then re-parsed to an object with the same structure and values) can easily be *duplicated* with:
>
> ```
> var newObj = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( someObj ) );
> ```
>
> Of course, that requires you to ensure your object is JSON safe. For some situations, that's trivial. For others, it's insufficient.

What is a "JSON-safe" object? I ran a few tests with JavaScript and so far most things (arrays, numbers, strings, objects) can be duplicated using the above line, except for methods (`foo.bar`), when trying to duplicate a method, `undefined` is inserted in the method's place in the duplicated object.

Comment: I assume it means that any value inside the object must be serializable to JSON and back. That's not the case for `NaN`, `+0` vs `-0`, `undefined`, functions, `Date`s or class/constructor instances.

Comment: @FelixKling Could you post that as an answer (with a bit more elaboration, hopefully) ?

Comment: @FelixKling Aren't `Date`s and `class/constructor` instances just functions 
 (in Javascript, at least) ?

Comment: I mean the values you get when you call `new Date()` and `new MyClass()`. Those values are not functions. Symbols cannot be serialized to JSON either btw.

Comment: @FelixKling You are talking about the direct `prototype` property, not the internal `[[prototype]]`, right ? So, in that regard, `RegExp` and other built-in JavaScript objects are not eligible either, am i correct ?

Comment: @FelixKling Seems weird, but isn't what you get using `new MyClass()` just a simple object ? Because an object like `{foo: "bar"}` is serializable.

Comment: No, I'm talking about `[[prototype]]`. Only functions have `prototype` properties and we already established that those are not serializable. But you are right, it basically applies to all *instances* of built in "classes" such as RegExp, Set, Map, Date, etc.

Comment: `new MyClass()` returns an object whose internal `[[prototype]]` property points to `MyClass.prototype`. You loose that connection when *unserializing* the data.

Comment: @FelixKling `new Date()` instances can be successfully duplicated using the example I provided. However, just like you said, their prototypes act weird, the duplicate `Date`'s `[[prototype]]` is set to `String.prototype`.

Comment: Though we could say that the behavior i talked about in my previous comment can be pronounced serialization-unsafe. In your opinion, should we pronounce it as such  ?

Answer (score 3):

To get `foo`<=> `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))` as true, we must be able to represent `foo` in the [JSON format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

JSON only supports:

> Number: a signed decimal number that may contain a fractional part and may use exponential E notation, but cannot include non-numbers like NaN. The format makes no distinction between integer and floating-point. JavaScript uses a double-precision floating-point format for all its numeric values, but other languages implementing JSON may encode numbers differently.

> String: a sequence of zero or more Unicodecharacters. Strings are delimited with double-quotation marks and support a backslash escaping syntax.

> Boolean: either of the values true or false

> Array: an ordered list of zero or more values, each of which may be of any type. Arrays use square bracket notation with elements being comma-separated.

> Object: an unordered collection of name/value pairs where the names (also called keys) are strings. Since objects are intended to represent associative arrays,[12] it is recommended, though not required,[13] that each key is unique within an object. Objects are delimited with curly brackets and use commas to separate each pair, while within each pair the colon ':' character separates the key or name from its value.

> null: An empty value, using the word null

In javascript, the concept of `JSON safe object` basically refers to a javascript object that can be represented in the JSON format without any loss.

Comment: But, `var obj = { 
x: true
};

console.log(obj === JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
` prints out false, although nothing is lost.

Comment: two object-holding variables are only equal if they reference the same variable. So i believe `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` is never going to be `===` anything except for a reference to itself.

Comment: Edited from `===` to equivalence for consistency

Comment: @Taurus What's that has to do with reference equality ?  it is never going to be the same. Just like Felix said - there are some values that can't be 1:1 match like undefined +0 etc.

Comment: @RoyiNamir OP had this line before their edit (they were saying that nothing must be lost during the duplication process in order for this to evaluate to true): `foo === JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))`, I was just trying to say no matter what, `foo` will never be `===` to the result of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))`.